# The target "GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker" does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to pack a custom project (with other custom projects as dependencies) via [Nugetizer3000](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Build.Packaging). I've chosen this one because apparently it's the only "packer" that currently works in VS2017.

For some of my projects, it works out of the box:

1. Install [the VS2017 extension](https://storage.googleapis.com/appveyor-artifacts/mobileessentials-14943/nuget-build-packaging/1-0-326-dev/995ag271b24r0yvc/out/NuGetizer3000-VS2017.vsix?GoogleAccessId=646512516365-bidt3t59mctt8vti6cffe2sbq65pnmb1@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1489660563&Signature=Y8J0bDmd4bSEoOTXvpZpLcpDYAmS9ijOw6HKGmHPIwasUUFZYIcXxkn4nwLnUKB02D51kRCO58UQwXBOxB0J2JHIM9qVP1x9LtC0Zz%2f9hl%2fFgm6toOVppP28IQ%2bhqh5z2pHbm8ZnPHpWKK%2bmpwNaSZ6bXtAZwp7PbO4KIO2ZLQsnkAlQSVEKjx%2bSDnMg3jnxHJMzQ1UOAdUbBJBXLCNvtFBu3GBU2kSJHxvSgCSuEZezfaEwqxI1EFMofkhucAaKchClO9nJfMNVaIUsxQ23A3A4G%2fI5Uqa%2fJJdZEYLrwlc9Hdg%2bEObPrWICQRRbm52S2jH4aDJ9xpa6mTCsAQgqKg%3d%3d)
2. Right-click on the project (in VS2017)
3. "Create NuGet Package"
4. Done: `Created package at \src\MyProjName\bin\Debug\MyProjName.0.0.1.nupkg.`

But for a particular project, I get the following error:

```
The target "GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker" does not exist in the project.  MyProjectName   C:\path\to\MyProjectName.csproj
```

[This closed issue](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Build.Packaging/pull/68) is most the relevant thing I've found, but I don't find a solution to my problem in it.

Comment: I've received [an answer from bbowman (the author of NuGet.Build.Packaging) via github](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Build.Packaging/pull/68#issuecomment-287095794), which I am still trying to figure out: "You should make sure MyProjectName has that target. This is used to detect if the project has nugetizer installed. This target is part of the common props / targets shared by all projects so probably you should make sure your custom one does this as well."

Comment: What I take out from this info is that if I want to pack ProjectA (ProjectA depends on ProjectB + ProjectC), I should first be able to pack ProjectB and ProcectC separately. I currently can't: one of the projects works on "rebuild all" but when packing the project it fails with `error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "Build".`. Trying to figure out that one first (currently investigating [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4381#issuecomment-274932738)).